# Modifying Scala GUI's outside of object

Tags: scala, user-interface

I have a GUI ive created in Scala. Its very simple but I would like to modify the DSLOutput object from outside of DSLGUI. Does anyone know how I can call DSLOutput.append() from outside of the DSLGUI? Ive tried importing DSLGUI but I cant seems to figure out how to access DSLOutput.

```
package api
import swing._
import event._

object DSLGUI extends SimpleSwingApplication{

  def top = new MainFrame{
    title = "Computer Repair Advisory System"
    object Commands extends TextField(columns = 50)
    object DSLOutput extends TextArea(rows = 15, columns = 50)
    object SendCommand extends Button("Send")
    val CommandPanel = new FlowPanel{
      contents += Commands
      contents += SendCommand
    }
    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical){
        contents +=CommandPanel
        contents += DSLOutput
    }
    listenTo(SendCommand)
    reactions += {
      case ButtonClicked(SendCommand) =>
        DSLOutput append "Test "


    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to declare it in the scope of `DSLGUI`, rather than as a local object within your `top` method. Then you can access it with `DSLGUI.DSLOutput`.

i.e.

```
object DSLGUI extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  object DSLOutput extends TextArea(rows = 15, columns = 50)

  def top = new MainFrame {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh how simple! I hate it when i stare at code for an our and trying to decipher random toString's on these objects. Thanks so much!